# getting code 400 message Bad request syntax , after post from flutter

Tags: django, flutter

getting code 400 message Bad request syntax , after post from flutter,

with postman request send and no problem but with flutter after Post Map data to Django server i get this error

```
[19/May/2020 14:58:13] "POST /account/login/ HTTP/1.1" 406 42
[19/May/2020 14:58:13] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('32')
[19/May/2020 14:58:13] "32" 400 -
```

Django

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def login_user(request):
    print(request.data)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        response = request.data
        username = response.get('username')
        password = response.get('password')
        if password is not None and username is not None:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                create_or_update_token = Token.objects.update_or_create(user=user)
                user_token = Token.objects.get(user=user)
                return Response({'type': True, 'token': user_token.key, 'username': user.username},
                                status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response({'type': False, 'message': 'User Or Password Incorrect'},
                                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        else:
            return Response({'type': False, 'message': 'wrong parameter'}, status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
    else:
        return Response({'type': False, 'message': 'method is wrong'}, status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

flutter

```
Future<dynamic> postGoa(String endpoint, Map data)async{
    Map map = {
      "username":"user",
      "password":"password"
    };
    var url = _getUrl("POST", endpoint);
    var client = new HttpClient();
    HttpClientRequest request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
    request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ athenticated
    );
    request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(map)));
    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
    String mydata= await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
    client.close();

    return mydata;
  }

}
```

after add

```
request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(map)));
```

i get error in Django console

Comment: Is there any reason you're using `HttpClient` instead of the `http` package on pub.dev?

Comment: Update the question showing the postman request page.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using HttpClient instead of the http package on pub.dev?  Dart:io

Comment: curl --location --request POST 'http://192.168.1.105/account/login/' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer mona_krp' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
 "username":"mrhaydari",
 "password":"PowerM@@2024"
}' post man request

Comment: Is there any reason you're using HttpClient instead of the http package on pub.dev? Dart:io

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out your request headers from the Django application.

```
print(request.headers)
```

I bet one of the headers is `Content-Type: ''`. If that is the case, Django isn't reading your POST data because it thinks there is no data. I recommend calculating the length of the content you are sending in Flutter, then sending the correct Content-Length header with your request.

That might look something like this (in your Flutter app):

```
encodedData = jsonEncode(data); // jsonEncode is part of the dart:convert package
request.headers.add(HttpHeaders.contentLengthHeader, encodedData.length);
```